# Is there a way to send a packet to 255.255.255.255 using TCP?

Tags: c++, sockets

I have been trying to understand broadcast and multicast, and got to know how with the help of UDP, we can send broadcast packets to 255.255.255.255
However, what can we do when we are doing the same through TCP?

Here's my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    const char* broadcastAddress = "255.255.255.255";
    int broadcastPort = 12345; // Use a specific port number

    int udpSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (udpSocket == -1) {
        perror("Failed to create socket");
        return 1;
    }

    // Enable broadcasting on the socket
    int broadcastEnable = 1;
    if (setsockopt(udpSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcastEnable, sizeof(broadcastEnable)) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to enable broadcasting");
        // close(udpSocket);
        return 1;
    }

    // Set up the destination address
    struct sockaddr_in broadcastAddr;
    memset(&broadcastAddr, 0, sizeof(broadcastAddr));
    broadcastAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    broadcastAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(broadcastAddress);
    broadcastAddr.sin_port = htons(broadcastPort);

    // Message to broadcast
    const char* message = "This is a broadcast message";

    // Send the message to the broadcast address
    if (sendto(udpSocket, message, strlen(message), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&broadcastAddr, sizeof(broadcastAddr)) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to send broadcast message");
    }

    // Close the socket
    close(udpSocket);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried changing SOCK_DGRAM to SOCK_STREAM in order to make it a TCP Connection.
Running the program does not send any packet, as is visible with Wireshark running in the background not showing any change

Comment: Can you explain how you expect it to work? What do you expect to actually `connect` to, for this TCP connection?

Comment: You cannot simply broadcast with TCP.
TCP is a connection-oriented protocol, and it operates point-to-point, meaning it establishes a direct, two-way connection between a client and a server. There is no concept of broadcasting in TCP because it's designed for reliable, connection-based communication, and it's not meant for sending data to multiple recipients simultaneously.

Comment: @sam Good point, I retract that comment.  Thinking back (it was a long time ago...), we were using UDP.  Apologies.  But it's still not wise OP.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik my aim is to constantly keep sending a status packet as a broadcast to all devices in a local network. Was wondering if I can use TCP for the same

Comment: Why do you think you need to use TCP, when you just described exactly how UDP works? If you're sending "a broadcast to all devices" then you're not `connect`ing to any specific device. A TCP connection is, by definition, a connection between two endpoints. No more. No less.

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot send a packet to 255.255.255.255 using TCP in the same way you do with UDP. It is a special IP address used for broadcast communication in IPv4, and is specific to UDP.

TCP is a connection-oriented protocol, it establishes a connection between two specific endpoints (IP addresses and ports) for reliable, point-to-point communication. It doesn't have a built-in mechanism for broadcasting to multiple recipients as UDP.

To achieve broadcasting-like behavior with TCP, you would need to create a server that accepts multiple incoming connections effectively creating a one-to-many communication model.

Comment: _To achieve broadcasting-like behavior with TCP, you would need to create a server that accepts multiple incoming connections_ There is a sort of middle way: send broadcast packets over UDP and acknowledge them via TCP.  The sender then needs some kind of retry strategy for dropped packets (this is what we did, back in the day).

Comment: ‘ To achieve broadcasting-like behavior with TCP, you would need to create a server that accepts multiple incoming connections’: nearly all TCP servers accept multiple connections, but that doesn’t constitute broadcast in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: @user207421 I think the implication is that once multiple connections have been accepted, the server can then send a copy of data out on each connected socket to "broadcast" it.  (yes, it's still not really broadcast, but the achieved affect is similar)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner What if we do not know how many exact sockets are to be connected? Is there a generalised version for this?

Comment: @Mayank there is no need to know the number that will be connected; you can store the file descriptors in a data structure (e.g std::set) that will hold an arbitrary number of items and iterate over that when you want to send-to-all.